# Ошибка при запуске exe(Pyinstaller) файла python с использованием модуля PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

Доброго времени суток.

При попытке создание exe файла с помощью PyInstaller-a столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

При открытии екзешника из консоли сделанного с помощью PyInstaller командой: pyinstaller -F --exclude PyQt5 "S:\Users\Silin\python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt designer\apps\test app\main.py", в консоль выводится такая ошибка:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
[3460] Failed to execute script**
main и файл не запускается.
При этом если создавать exe с флагом -w(глушить консоль), что мне и надо, то получаю уже вот такую ошибку:
[image]

и программа всё равно не запускается.
Вот что находится main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
self = Ui_MainWindow()
self.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def bp0():
    self.lineEdit.setText("Hello!")

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если создавать exe без PyQt5 то всё прекрасно работает.
Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Comment: опубликуйте `main.py`

Comment: Попробуйте следующее: 1. исправьте опечатку `def bp0():` на `def bp():`. 2. Находясь в папке, где у вас находятся `main.py` и `design.py` - выполните `pyinstaller -F -w main.py` .

Comment: 1 попробовал, всё равно та же ошибка.

Comment: 2-ое тоже, всё равно не запускается.

Comment: И к стати, файл создаётся только при ручном включении модуля PyQt5 в него, командой --exclude PyQt5. если же создавать exe без --exclude PyQt5, то он не создаётся и в консоль выводится ошибка: Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: S:/users/èíòåðíåò óðîê/python/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins

Comment: `èíòåðíåò óðîê` ? — не используйте кириллицу.

Comment: Почему это? Я всегда так делаю это не как и не на что не влияет